# Terraform (v0.7.4) and Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation

Tags: google-cloud-sql, terraform

Does Terraform (v0.7.4) support Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation instance creation/management?

I can't find any reference to it being supported or not available on the Terraform website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform's [google_sql_database_instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html) resources works fine with Google Cloud SQL Second Generation instances, the only difference being in the tiers that are used.

Simply choosing one of the [second generation tiers](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-pricing) such as `db-n1-standard-1` vs a [first generation tier](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#1st-gen-pricing) such as `D1` will then create a second generation instance.